# Need to find the User id

Tags: unix

Can anyone give solution how to find the user id in `/etc/passwd` file:

```
ssconfig:x:59998:60001:Sun StorEdge(tm) Configuration Service Config:/:/bin/false
boxi:x:60008:100::/export/home/boxi:/bin/csh
```

I need to find the User in 60008.

Answer (score 0):

For your eyes only: `grep 60008 /etc/passwd`

For a script of some sort, I can't think of anything better than this: `perl -E 'say scalar getpwuid shift' 60008`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '$3 == 60008 {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

would be a clean standard solution. The line may be read as: Check in the file with colon-seperated fields for lines where the 3rd field equals 60008 and from the lines found print out the 1st value.